# Is it possible that I create table in postgresql and import those tables in models.py in django?

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-models

I want to make table using create table command

Comment: You can do that with the `inspectdb` management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Comment: But this is typically only used for *legacy* databases, since a model can specify more sophisticated validation, etc. than a database.